# I want to add a custom attribute to model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to add an extra attribute to my laravel model without using get Attribute. i want to get created_at attribute in both default and custom format.

```
default : created_at : 2018-07-25 15:38:56

second: 10 Days Ago
```

if i use getCreatedAtAttribute() it changes the default attribute.

Comment: Just change the name of the custom attribute. Use something like getDaysCreatedAttribute() or similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your model, add this:

`protected $appends = ['readable_created_at'];`

```
public function getReadableCreatedAtAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at; //or however you want to manipulate it
}
```

After which, you can access it like normal, e.g. `$user->readable_created_at`.

Read more at the [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) here.